# is there a way to get access to a cell, when you know the index (as Integer)? 

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

In my table the text of the last cell becomes editable when pressing an edit-Button. But how can I get access to the cell?   I know the "number" of it (size of Array, the table is built of), but how can I get the indexPath (if needed) out of it and how can I get access to the cell?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to update the text in the array. Then reload the table to update it's text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that you're now in edit mode, then you reload the cell in question:

```
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourIndex inSection:yourSection];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you then need to return a corresponding cell if the you are in edit mode.

Note that you should not query the cell directly to modify it as you will get a *different* cell than the one that's currently displayed. Even if it were the same, your modification would be lost for example when the cell scrolls out of sight and becomes visible again.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourIndex inSection:yourSection];
UITableViewCell *cel = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
```

Comment: And modifying this cell will fail. You won't receive the instance that's displayed on screen.